# SQL Server Table Join issue

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am Trying to join three tables and I an getting cross rows data (Getting 6 rows instead of 3). I tried inner,left and right join same result. Could you please help me.

**Table 1**

```
SELECT PATIENT,TDACTDATE,TDACTTIME,TDVALUE 
FROM NurDocumentedResults A 
WHERE (INTBASE = '400130') 
    AND (TDQUERY = 'NURPTVALUE') 
    AND (TDACTDATE = '20120425') 
AND TDVALUE >='8.0' AND A.PATIENT='F126'
```

Result I am getting

```
F126    20120425    1715    8.8
F126    20120425    1840    8.4
F126    20120425    2300    9.7
```

**Table 2**

```
SELECT B.PATIENT,A.TESTRESULTDATE,A.TESTRESULTTIME,A.RESULT 
FROM LabLSpecResultTests A
INNER JOIN LabLSpecimenFile B 
    ON A.URN=B.URN 
    AND A.TESTRESULTDATE=B.COLLECTIONDATE 
WHERE A.TESTRESULTDATE='20120425' 
    AND (A.TEST IN ('100.0100', '100.0120', '100.0130', '100.0110')) 
    AND (A.RESULT > '8.0') 
    AND B.PATIENT='F126'
```

Result I am getting

```
F126    20120425    1756    8.5
F126    20120425    2335    9.2
```

**When I join all three Tables,**

```
SELECT D.PATIENT,TDACTDATE,TDACTTIME,TDVALUE,A.RESULT,A.RESULTTIME,A.TESTRESULTDATE,A.TESTRESULTTIME
FROM NurDocumentedResults D 
LEFT OUTER JOIN LabLSpecimenFile B 
    ON D.PATIENT=B.PATIENT AND D.TDACTDATE=B.COLLECTIONDATE
INNER JOIN LabLSpecResultTests A 
    ON A.URN=B.URN 
    AND A.TESTRESULTDATE=B.COLLECTIONDATE
WHERE (INTBASE = '400130') 
    AND (TDQUERY = 'NURPTVALUE') 
    AND (TDACTDATE = '20120425') 
    AND TDVALUE >='8.0' 
    AND A.TESTRESULTDATE='20120425' 
    AND  (A.TEST IN ('100.0100', '100.0120', '100.0130', '100.0110')) 
    AND (A.RESULT > '8.0') 
    AND D.PATIENT='F126'
```

**I am getting following Result**

```
F126    20120425    1715    8.8 8.5 2463    20120425    1756
F126    20120425    1840    8.4 8.5 2463    20120425    1756
F126    20120425    2300    9.7 8.5 2463    20120425    1756
F126    20120425    1715    8.8 9.2 22789   20120425    2335
F126    20120425    1840    8.4 9.2 22789   20120425    2335
F126    20120425    2300    9.7 9.2 22789   20120425    2335
```

Comment: What is the result that you want?

Comment: You have a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and a `WHERE` clause that references columns from the right side of the join.  It doesn't allow them to be `NULL`, thus negating the `OUTER`.  Either move them to an appropriate `ON` clause, or modify them to accept `NULL`s.

Comment: @RBarryYoung 
I should have 3 rows only not 6. if we look at last result, rows are duplicated

Comment: @Matt: No, the are no duplicate rows, every row in your output is unique and distinct.  If you want us to help you, please identify the three rows that you think should be there, and then why the other three should not be there.

Comment: @RBarryYoung 
I am trying to get following result
F126 20120425 1715 8.8 8.5 2463 20120425  1756
F126 20120425 1840 8.4 9.2 22789 20120425  2335
F126 20120425 2300 9.7 Null Null Null    Null

Comment: @Matt:  put in your post.  Multi-line code and data is unreadable in the comments.  And don' forget to explain why those three should be there and the other three should not.

Answer (score 0):

recommendation: You may do a join from your first table to a Select statement that joins the other two. Sorry for not writing the actual query
I dont have sql on this machine to write the query since i'm on linux

Try something like
Select TableA.*
from TableA
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Fields From TableB LEFT JOIN TABLEC ON TableB ... = TableC ) AS JOIN_TABLE
ON TableA.Field = JOIN_TABLE.Field

Try something like this, it might work as you want.

Comment: I got 53 rows by following

SELECT D.PATIENT,TDACTDATE,TDACTTIME,TDVALUE FROM NurDocumentedResults D 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT PATIENT,TESTRESULTDATE,TESTRESULTTIME,RESULT FROM LabLSpecResultTests A
LEFT JOIN LabLSpecimenFile B ON A.URN=B.URN AND A.TESTRESULTDATE=B.COLLECTIONDATE 
WHERE A.TESTRESULTDATE='20120425' AND (A.TEST IN ('100.0100', '100.0120', '100.0130', '100.0110')) AND (A.RESULT > '8.0') AND B.PATIENT='F126') AS JOIN_TABLE ON D.PATIENT=JOIN_TABLE.PATIENT AND TDACTDATE=TESTRESULTDATE WHERE (INTBASE = '400130') AND (TDQUERY = 'NURPTVALUE') AND (TDACTDATE = '20120425') AND TDVALUE >='8.0'